# duplicate headers received from server using Struts2

Tags: java, http, struts2, http-headers, content-disposition

I am using Struts2 in an application. I need to download excel file(.xlsx and .xls formats). This is working properly in IE but in Chrome it is showing error

> "Duplicate headers received from server"

I use quotes before the file name("<File Name"). Still it is not working in chrome. Below is the code snippets used in my application.

struts.xml

```xml
<action name="*Excel" method="{1}" class="ReportUtilityAction">
    <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">application/vnd.ms-excel</param>
        <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
        <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

I have mentioned the content-disposition in the action class as

```java
static final private String Content = "Content-Disposition";

HttpServletResponse response = this.getHttpResponse();
response.setHeader(Content, "attachment;filename='Export.xlsx';");
```

Comment: If you are using `stream` result then use it to set content disposition header also.

Comment: @AleksandrM I have used the content disposition through action class. is that what you have asked me to try? I am not able to get you. Could you explain in detail?

Comment: `stream` result already sets this header and you are adding another one hence this error. Read docs about `stream` result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `contentDisposition` in the same way you've set the other headers: in struts configuration.

```xml
<result name="success" type="stream">
    <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="Export.xlsx";</param>
    <param name="contentType">application/vnd.ms-excel</param>
    <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
    <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
</result>
```

You can also have it parameterized by using the `${}` notation, with a corresponding getter in the Action:

```xml
<param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${filename}";</param>
```

```java
public String getFilename(){ ... }
```

Comment: I tried this. still i am getting the same error in chrome

Comment: You obviously need to remove the `response.setHeader(Content, "attachment;filename='Export.xlsx';");` part from your action

Comment: Ensure you've redeployed correctly and nothing is cached

Comment: Thank you Andrea. Once i cleared my cache it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the header field is set twice; you should be able to see that in an HTTP trace. Thus you need to find out *why* it's set twice.